# doctrine 1.2 how to get an object by id?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

How can i get an object using his Id in doctrine 1.2 ?

Without writing sql or Dql.
I did not find it in the docs: 
https://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/working-with-models.html#fetching-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$user = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->find(1);
```

Here you go for doctrine 1.2

there is a reference here... but nowhere in doc where you would expect it :(
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/working-with-models.html#retrieving-related-records

Comment: what's the translation of "dakmdaklsd alksdlkamsd kldlksmdklm" ?

Comment: i think the document writer either had a seizure or he was a profound fan of the klingon language